# Can a theorem determine its own complexity?

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, kolmogorov-complexity

Much how Gödel spoke of the Incompleteness Theorems, can a theorem determine its own complexity?

Namely, I haven't seen a concise proof of the following that is not possible to determine in the language of logic (Kolmogorov Complexity); yet, to state this mathematically I am unable to do at the moment:

Can it be positively proven when the proof of the theorem is irreducibly complex up to the least amount of computational steps required for a theorem's proof to Q.E.D.

Comment: I don't really understand what most of this post means, but it sounds like you're asking something like "Can we tell that we've found the *shortest possible* proof of a given theorem?" If so, the answer is **yes** since we can always just brute-force-search through the finitely many shorter possible proofs; if not, I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I believe that my point coincides with stating that without knowing the completeness of a theorem can it be determined how complex it is? The brute-force approach seems like it isn't Turing computable or at least something not an ordinary non-AI computer would be able to compute without knowing the completeness of the theorem.

Comment: What is the "completeness" of a theorem? And how are you measuring complexity?

Comment: The only method I know-of is Kolmogorov complexity of determining a theorems complexity by its proof. So, I can't think of anything else at the moment.